# How do I create an array of 3D coordinates in Python?

Tags: python

I was wondering what would be an efficient way to create an array of coordinates of a 3d space.
For example:

```
[ [x,y,z] ,for x in range(1000) for y in range(1000) for z in range(1000) ]
```

will take allot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Numpy and the mgrid function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html

But the main problem is that you allocating a lot of memory and that will always be slow. Maybe you could write your program with a smaller resolution and do 10 steps at once?